# MPD with Bluetooth

Tags: audio, bluetooth, streaming, audio-playback, mpd

Is it possible to run MPD with bluetooth in the Pi?

Currently many guides which I have seen are mostly utilizing Upnp/Wifi setup to run. Now this is fine if there was only Apple devices. Since Airplay is sytem wide. Any music from any app can be streamed.

But in Android there isn't anything. Apps need to support Chromecast otherwise the music controller app itself needs to hook with multitude of services. Nothing is elegant on Android.

Now this is a problem.

So I was wondering if MPD can be used with Bluetooth. So any music from any type of phone can be streamed and with MPD one can have networked audio as well as shared playlist.

How can we do this?

Comment: Not only one word about Raspberry Pi. Why do you speaking about Android?

Comment: I am trying to run MPD with Bluetooth in RPi. I listed the reason why MPD with other systems is not what I am looking for, in case someone points that out. But your quip I didn't forsee.

Comment: Umm, what's the problem? Start pulseaudio, let mpd talk to it, pair with bluetooth speaker, tell pulseaudio to send audio to it.

Answer (score 0):

You can activate shout to run a **shout stream** over **wifi**. there are heaps of clients that can play these streams on *iOS* and *Android*.

/etc/mpd.conf

```
audio_output {
       type            "shout"
       encoder         "vorbis"                # optional
       name            "My Shout Stream"
       host            "localhost"
       port            "8000"
       mount           "/mpd.ogg"
       password        "hackme"
       quality         "5.0"
       bitrate         "128"
       format          "44100:16:1"
#       protocol        "icecast2"              # optional
#       user            "source"                # optional
#       description     "My Stream Description" # optional
#       url             "http://example.com"    # optional
#       genre           "jazz"                  # optional
#       public          "no"                    # optional
#       timeout         "2"                     # optional
#       mixer_type      "software"              # optional
}
```